# Print out an user input correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to replace text in an user input with an variable.
I wrote an little demo code, to show you my problem:

```
puts "Enter your feeling"
a = gets.chomp
@feel = "good"
puts a
```

SO when it comes to the input, i type in:

```
Actually i fell very #{@feel}
```

Then i hope to get this output:

```
 Actually i fell very good
```

But instead i get this output:

```
 Actually i fell very #{@feel}
```

What did i make wrong?

Comment: The thing is i dont really get helpful answers

Comment: If you didn't get helpful answers it's probably because your question is not worded well or lacks information. Instead of posting the exact same question, try modifying the previous question instead. (I've provided an answer on the other one)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Kernal#eval

```
eval ("a")
```

Comment: `eval` user input is a bad idea. Hope that nobody something like `File.rm_f`.

Comment: can you post the full code please?

Answer (score -1):

**#{variable} works only double quotes (" "). So you try inside of "". if you use this ' ', it will consider as string**

Comment: Yes i know, so how can i change this?

Comment: While your statement is technically correct, it doesn't help at all in the context of the question because the text is not parsed as code by Ruby.

Comment: Don't abuse bold type in an answer. Instead, learn to use the various formatting options, and format for clarity and readability.